# showing quick launch in a provider hosted app

Tags: 2013, branding, provider-hosted-app

So ive just started creating apps and have successfully created a simple provider hosted app.  Is it possible to display the quick launch bar and use a the default master page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the best approach in this case is create an app-part which will display your page and add it to a page on your host-web.

Comment: Thanks for that. It seems like a good idea.  To be honest at this moment im not really getting the whole provider hosted app thing.  I added a list to the app web but couldnt seem to create a simple link from the apps default.aspx page to it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a little Alexander? Does this mean you would create an app-part on a SharePoint page, which would display a page(s) from a provider-hosted app/add-in?